# Is it possible to connect a data source in Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, analytics, dashboard, telemetry

I have to create a dashboard with google analytics but my data is in JSON format! Is it possible to import the static data so that I can create my dashboard? I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

an example of solution is to import your json data to a google sheet and connect this to google analytics

watch these videos

import json to sheet
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW1KGPe-zfU

connect a sheet to analytic
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6Nvp51Z5rw